# React material UI dark theme apply only for the drawer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I do want to apply dark theme **only for the drawer component**.

**In Drawer.js**

```js
 <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <div>
      {props.token && (
        <Drawer
          anchor="left"
          open={props.isDrawerOpen}
          onClose={onToggle("left", false)}
          variant="persistent"
        >
          {list("left")}
        </Drawer>
      )}
    </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
```

I import this **Drawer.js** in the **App.js** like this

```js
<Router history={history}>
          <div className={classes.root}>
            <NavBar />
            <Drawer />
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" exact component={Login}></Route>
              <Route path="/country" exact component={Country}></Route>
              <Route path="/user-create" exact component={User}></Route>
              <Route path="/users" exact component={UsersList}></Route>
              <Route path="/countries" exact component={Countries}></Route>
              <Route path="/company" exact component={Company}></Route>
              <Route path="/companies" exact component={CompanyList}></Route>

              <Route component={NotFound}></Route>
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
```

dark theme applied to the Drawer. But not only drawer I applied to the other components as well. How do I apply dark theme only for the Drawer component?

Answer (score 0):

Please check these steps first:

- Make sure the `theme` passed in `ThemeProvider` component is only used for that `Drawer` only.
- If you use multiple `ThemeProvider` in one project, please make sure each provider should have separate `theme`. Otherwise, shared `theme` will effects everything.
- When the action "change theme" happen? And does it effect to the right `theme` that you passed above?

After that, everything should be fine.